sqlalchemy session "Cannot use autocommit mode with future=True."
Since which version sqlalchemy session "Cannot use autocommit mode with future=True."?
https://rattailproject.org/docs/wuttjamaican/_modules/sqlalchemy/orm/session.html
        if autocommit:
            if future: <-- I don't really get this...
                raise sa_exc.ArgumentError(
                    "Cannot use autocommit mode with future=True."
                )
            self.autocommit = True
        else:
            self.autocommit = False

This is breaking changes, I found out only after I had to reinstall Anaconda.
Python 3.9.19 (main, Mar 21 2024, 17:21:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> print(sqlalchemy.__version__)
1.4.32
>>>

Anyone else run into this?
In the past, session.flush() with auto-commit = True will propagate changes to database.
Now:
session.flush()  <-- Should I remove Flush altogether?
session.commit()

Thanks

future was added in 1.4, where it is False by default. In 2.0 it always True. For session(autocommit=) see here.

If you set future=True on your engine or sessions then you need to review the Migration Guide.

Thanks Snakecharmerb. You're right, and I digged into migration guide: "SQLAlchemy’s first releases were at odds with the spirit of the Python DBAPI (PEP 249) in that it tried to hide PEP 249’s emphasis on “implicit begin” and “explicit commit” of transactions. Fifteen years later we now see this was essentially a mistake,"

From Snake's (thanks) comment above, sqlalchemy put in this breaking change because they think it is appropriate: "SQLAlchemy’s first releases were at odds with the spirit of the Python DBAPI (PEP 249) in that it tried to hide PEP 249’s emphasis on “implicit begin” and “explicit commit” of transactions. Fifteen years later we now see this was essentially a mistake ..."
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/changelog/migration_20.html
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(..., future=True)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(some_table.insert().values(foo="bar"))
    conn.commit()

    conn.execute(text("some other SQL"))
    conn.rollback()

Regardless, I hate breaking changes.
